# Need to keep keyboard focus on OpenCV window in Python on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, opencv, user-interface, pyqt

I'm opening multiple windows in a Python code and need the OpenCV window to maintain keyboard focus. I can do this on Windows OS, and OS-X does this automatically I think since the other windows can't accept key presses, but I need help on Linux. I believe I have the correct statement commented out in the code to keep the window active, but I need to get the window handle (`QWidget.window()`) from the OpenCV window name 'cv2window'. Below is an example code that keeps focus if `window_focus("cv2window")` is not commented out. I just need to finish getting the Linux version to work.

```py
    import sys
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib as mpl
    import PyQt6 as qt  # Must be before import of matplotlibl.pyplot
    mpl.use('qtagg')    # Use the QT backend
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        import warnings
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore", UserWarning )  # Fix Windows warning
        sys.coinit_flags = 2
        from pywinauto.findwindows import find_window    # Windows OS window focus
        import win32gui
    #elif sys.platform == "darwin":
        #import AppKit    # pip install pyobjc       Mac OS window focus
    elif "linux" in sys.platform:
        print( "Linux support in development" )
    
    def window_focus( window_name ):
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(find_window(title=window_name))
        #elif sys.platform == "darwin":    # OSX doesn't seem to need this to maintain focus
            #cv2.setWindowProperty(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_TOPMOST, 1)
            #AppKit.NSApplication.sharedApplication().activateIgnoringOtherApps_(1)
        elif "linux" in sys.platform:
            print( "Linux support in development" )
            #qt.QtWidgets.QMainWindow.setWindowState( 0, qt.QtCore.Qt.WindowActive )
            # Error says first arg must be QWidget type so still need window handle
    
    img = cv2.imread( "python_colors.png" )
    t = np.arange( 0.0, 2.0, 0.01 )
    s = np.sin( 2 * np.pi * t )
    fig = plt.figure( "MatPlotLibWindow" )
    plt.plot( t, s )
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
    
    while True:
    
        cv2.imshow( "cv2window", img )
    
        plt.plot( t, s )
        plt.show()
    
        window_focus( "cv2window" )
    
        while True:
            k = cv2.waitKey(0)
            if k != -1:    # Wait for any key press
                break
        if k == ord('x'):
            break
```

This works for OS-X and Windows but not for Linux yet.

Comment: Using while loops in UI toolkits is a **terrible** idea. Just don't do that, and avoid pseudo-procedural programming when dealing with such environments as it completely prevents proper event handling in their event loops and makes implementation extremely harder than it should.

Comment: Note that if your aim is to have an *always* active window that can grab keyboard events, then: 1. it's generally discouraged, especially for extremely generic key events like single letter ones; 2. if you are *really* aware of the above aspects, then you can consider using [`grabKeyboard()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grabKeyboard). Unfortunately, without knowing more about the behavior and expectations of your program, it's difficult to give you further help.

Comment: The grabKeyboard() you suggest or the setWindowState() both should work.  What I'm missing is the command to get the QWidget window handle from the OpenCV window name as in the win32 example.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you can get keyboard focused input by using `pynput` module or any other module which lets you get keyboard key-press. The term you are looking for is "HOT KEY". As far as I know **HOT KEYS** work even if the window is on background or not highlighted. If I am assigning a HOTKEY, it basically responds to the key-press even if you are not on that window.

Comment: The pynput package is one that I had not run across so thanks for pointing that out.  The OS-X requirements to run as root or whitelist the app, Python, and the terminal are more than I want to impose on users who will eventually download and install the full app so I think I still just need the proper commands to keep keyboard focus on the OpenCV window in Linux.

Comment: I also looked into the 'keyboard' Python package.  That points out that keyboard listeners will never work across ssh links since only the characters are sent.  I'm always open to these types of suggestions, but still think I just need the PyQt command to get the QWidget window handle from the OpenCV window name so that I can use WindowActivate to get focus.

Comment: There would be a way to keep window in focus via PyQt, will add here if I find the information

Comment: @DaveTurner Check this out https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/python-signal